# How to integrate JMETER (WEB DRIVER) to Azure pipeline

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, azure-pipelines, integration

Company requirements is to integrate JMETER WEB DRIVER(SELENIUM SCRIPTS) with AZURE PIPELINE so could anyone please help me the process please?

Could anyone Please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is going for [Mavenv3 Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/maven-v3?view=azure-pipelines)

You will need to create a [pom.xml file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) and specify JMeter version you will be using (latest is recommeded) and any plugins (I guess you will want to have [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) at least)

See [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) article for more information.

Example pom.xml file would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-webdriver:4.8.3.2</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Put your JMeter script(s) under `src/test/jmeter` folder relative to the pom.xml file and use `verify` as the Maven goal.

End-to-end instructions: [JMeter and Azure pipelines](https://medium.com/@gabriel.starczewski/jmeter-and-azure-pipelines-55f0594239ac)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T . As I don't have much knowledge on Maven so Could you please let me know Jmeter Integration With Azure Pipeline without Maven please

Comment: If you want to start everything from scratch: 1. [Install JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation). 2. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/). 3. [Install WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) 4. [Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

Comment: Thanks for quick revert back. Could you please help me As part of the JMeter Integration With Azure Pipeline, Apche Maven installed version is 3.9.2 while using intelliJ Terminal and after executing the command as mvn clean verify getting as below:[ERROR]  re-run Maven with the -e switch.[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the followingarticles[E[Help1]http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionExceptionINFO] Shutdown detected, destroying JMeter process...